How do I repopulate a list with local storage json data?
This is my first time using this resource so bare with me.  I'm working on a choose your own adventure game.  I need to be able to take a ul, store it in local storage, and repopulate a ul on another page using the stored ul.  I have been trying to use json to do this as I have been given the impression that it is required but I am having trouble repopulating the ul on a new page.
    // itemList is the id for the UL I want to copy, it's size varies.  This is how I create/store it
    
         let item = document.createElement('li');
         let a = document.createElement("a");
      
         a.textContent = "New Item";
         a.setAttribute('href', "javascript:functionName()");
         
         let itemList = document.getElementById('inventory');
         item.appendChild(a);
   
         itemList.id = 'test';
         itemList.appendChild(item);

         localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(itemList));
      

    // from what I have found online this line should work I think for retrieving and repopulating 
        let textList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
        document.getElementById("testHTML").innerHTML = textList;

All I end up getting in my repopulated ul is undefined.  What am I missing?

Please share the exact error. There's no variable named ul in your script. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

You can't convert DOM elements to JSON. JSON can only be used for plain objects and arrays.

So extract the data you need from the elements, and save that. Then when you reload, you have to recreate the elements from this data.

@isherwood: itemList is the ul, pulled by id.  I'll be sure to note that in the future.  Thank you!

@Barmar oh that would be it.  Thank you!

You were close. You currently dont save the DOM Elements HTML, but the Object you got via the getElementById() Function. 
You need to save the innerHTML or outerHTML to the localStorage.
let item = document.createElement('li');
let a = document.createElement("a");

a.textContent = "New Item";
a.setAttribute('href', "javascript:functionName()");
 
let itemList = document.getElementById('inventory');
item.appendChild(a);

itemList.id = 'test';
itemList.appendChild(item);

localStorage.setItem("test", itemList.innerHTML);

let textList = localStorage.getItem("test");
document.getElementById("testHTML").innerHTML = textList;


Thank you for all the assistance.  I've got this problem sorted now.
